# img fill its container space without stretching

Tags: jquery, html, css, responsive-design

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5mneypc5/

It contains following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
.container {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: grey;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#c-width {
    width: 350px;
}
#c-height {
    height: 150px;
}

.container > img {
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container" id="c-width">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/cats/5">
</div>
<div class="container" id="c-height">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/500/250/cats/5">
</div>
```

Is it possible to make it fill whole container space, without being stretched? Cropping is allowed.

I tried both `min-height, max-width` and `max-height, min-width` cases, but each one only works for one of my containers.

Pure CSS is preferred; But JavaScript/jQuery solutions are welcomed, too.

Comment: Note that, image size is known (predefined), but container size is based on viewport size.

Answer (score 0):

Use a background image instead of an `img` element:

```
.container {
  background-image:url('../images/bg.png');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have to use `<img>` here.

Comment: I can't think of a use case when you have to use img.

Comment: a photo gallery, for example.

Comment: You can do a nice photo gallery without img tags. Why not?

Comment: Because image source urls gets from server in an AJAX request, then if I want to use backgrounds, I should use inline CSS.

Comment: You can set background images using JavaScript the same way as you add img tags. There is no difference here.

Answer (score 0):

```
.container img{
     width:100%;
}
```

Example- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/QEpJH/)

I think it help you

Answer (score 0):

On img use one at 100% and the other at auto depending on preference and image ratio. Also, you are giving the same div two different sizes.  One with a class, the other with an id. Pick one and then change with  @media for the device sizes if needed. Try that and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `max-width: 100%;` and `max-height: 100%;` to `min-width: 100%;` and `min-height: 100%;`

Here's an update to your fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/5mneypc5/1/

Comment: it won't crop the image at all.

Comment: But it is cropping the image.

Comment: yeah, i'm sorry. it crops, but doesn't resize image. if you remove `min-height` and `min-width`, the result is the same.

Comment: Didn't get you. I think it's not possible to both resize to 100%,100% and crop at the same time. If you resize it to 100%,100% it will stretch and if you crop it will not stretch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.,

```
.container > img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

I hope this is useful for u.,

Comment: Thanks, but it changes photo ratio.

Comment: yes definitely its happen because we changed a original width and height,